# Is there a way to reduce internal arrays on results?

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming a structure like this

```
        "_source": {
          "title": "Example Document",
          "versions": [
            {
              "page_id": "c5be72bb-dad2-4a66-969e-47b4c8bb47e9",
              "page_slug": "example-page-slug",
              "page_content": "this is an example of a matching string",
              "software_version": "2.0.0",
            },
            {
              "page_id": "2c24ffed-4f5b-471b-9def-595841912378",
              "page_slug": "example-page-slug",
              "page_content": "this is an example of a matching string",
              "software_version": "2.2.0",
            },
            {
              "page_id": "d1fa81c7-ad6a-4fb9-90e4-b146bd223530",
              "page_slug": "example-page-slug",
              "page_content": "this is a slightly different matching string",
              "software_version": "2.6.0",
            }
          ]
        }
```

The query that I send looks into `versions.page_content` for a match, so in this case (please excuse I'm using the PHP lib)

```
[ 'nested' => [ 
                'path' => 'versions', 
                    'query' => [
                      'query_string' => [
                          'fields' => [ 'versions.page_content'],
                          'query' => $q
                       ]
                     ] 
               ] 
]
```

This works fine, this works exactly as I had originally intended

The problem is, people are getting annoyed at seeing selectable Versions in the results page that do not contain what they searched for.

so if I looked for `"of a matching" example`

as of right now, this whole structure is returned and I render it out on our search results page.

What I am looking for is if ElasticSearch has the ability to, within it's query, to exclude nested objects that did not match, so i could maybe return

```
        "_source": {
          "title": "Example Document",
          "versions": [
            {
              "page_id": "c5be72bb-dad2-4a66-969e-47b4c8bb47e9",
              "page_slug": "example-page-slug",
              "page_content": "this is an example of a matching string",
              "software_version": "2.0.0",
            },
            {
              "page_id": "2c24ffed-4f5b-471b-9def-595841912378",
              "page_slug": "example-page-slug",
              "page_content": "this is an example of a matching string",
              "software_version": "2.2.0",
            }
          ]
        }
```

instead, or if ES has some kind of result post-processing ability so I may apply the string tokenization it did and I could apply it to subobjects myself.

Or am I doomed to have to do this all manually within my app after receiving results?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of query_string, maybe you should try [Bool queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/2.0/_search_operations.html#_match_query). They let you use something like must_not that brings everything that does NOT match the values.

If you just need some specific values from the object, use [_source](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-source-filtering). I'm not sure if PHP lets you use it that way. But yeah, you'll always get a weird response from the call and you'll have to iterate through it using your app.

Hope this is helpful! :D

Comment: The `query_string` op here is what is allowing the usage of google like syntax for the user (like wrapping double quotes around strict matches for example).  But nontheless the queries are returning the correct results, so there's no problem there. But also the `_source` attribute just removes specified fields, it's not applying any logic as to what fields to cull based on conditions of the found records.   Just seeing if ES has any built in way to handle removing certain versions from each result that themselves didn't quite match  inside of each record

Comment: I just got your point. Sorry. You will have to perform the filter in your code. Since at least one of the objects in the array satisfy the query, the whole object will be returned. You can't cut the array within the query.

Comment: Some people decide to change their design, like having n documents with one version instead of a single document with n versions. This might not be the best idea, but is an alternative

Comment: That last option is done mostly for performance. It takes a little bit less to return a doc with 5 fields instead of a doc with 2 fields with 3 nested fields and each with 6 arrays with at least 15 elements. The difference might not be that much (when cached, haha), but yeah, there are some changes in the performance.

Comment: Buuuut, you might want to run a script in Painless within your query. Don't trust the name, learning Painless is really painful (at the beginning). Painless lets you do some extra processing to your query and I'm sure there is a way to only get one single element from that list. However, I'm not sure if you can run it with PHP. Sorry for the bunch of comments. I was hi AF lol